# How to generate C# code from a SyntaxFactory CompilationUnitSyntax?

Tags: roslyn

I am building a simple AST using the code below.

```
output = SF
  .CompilationUnit()
  .WithMembers(SF.SingletonList<MemberDeclarationSyntax>(SF.ClassDeclaration("Class1")))
  .ToFullString();
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

The output is this:

```
classClass1{}
```

How can I get the output to look like C# code?

```
class Class1 {
}
```

ANSWSER: Call NormalizeWhitespace():

```
output = SF
  .CompilationUnit()
  .WithMembers(SF.SingletonList<MemberDeclarationSyntax>(SF.ClassDeclaration("Class1")))
  .NormalizeWhitespace()
  .ToFullString();
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call NormalizeWhitespace():

```
            output = SF
                .CompilationUnit()
                .WithMembers(SF.SingletonList<MemberDeclarationSyntax>(SF.ClassDeclaration("Class1")))
                .NormalizeWhitespace()
                .ToFullString();
            Console.WriteLine(output);
```